# On the set $\mathbb N$ we define the relation $\le’$ by the regulation $n\le’m$ ...

Tags: elementary-set-theory

On the set $\mathbb N$ we define the relation $\le’$ by the regulation $n\le’m$ exactly when $(2\mid n\text{ and } 2\not\mid m)$ or $(2\mid n\text{ and } 2\mid m\text{ and } n\le m)$ or $(2\not\mid n\text{ and }2\not\mid m\text{ and }n\le m)$.

Is $(\mathbb N,\le')$ isomorphic to $(\mathbb N,\le)$, where $\le$ is the usual arrangement on $\mathbb N$ ? Justify the answer.

**Experiment**: The sets $A$ and $B$ are isomorphic if there is a bijection $f:(A,\le_A)\to(B,\le_B)$, which is at the same time a strictly increasing function. In my opinion, these two sets are not isomorphic and so I have to somehow prove that such bijection does not exist. How about from here on out?

Comment: Please don't ask two completely distinct questions in the same post. Your first and second problems are completely separate.

Comment: Okay, so in response, you deleted the first question, which (i) is the one in the title; and (ii) the one that had been answered (forcing me to delete it, lest people wonder why I'm talking about something not on the post). Do you think that, perhaps, you messed up the choice? Downvoting, just because that was remarkably disingenuous.